# Stop showing error from HTTP or DIO request

Tags: flutter

I have a problem when I get an error request from API (when server response 500).
I am using **dio** or **http** plugin for **flutter** plug in.

The problem is that flutter does not show any error.

```
(DIO: resp.data, HTTP: resp.body)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this for exception handling

```
try {
    Response response = await dio.get('https://google.com');
    print(response.statusCode); // 500
    print(response.data); // Contains a Dio Error object
    } on DioError catch(e) {
        print(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Normally I always do that, but now it always skip this line - **print(response.data)**.

Comment: it will only go into the print(response.data) only when you get a status code between 200 - 299. Otherwise it will go to error.

Comment: Jaswant Singh, Thanks you

Answer (score 1):

You will retrieve in any case a Response object. According to the [DIO Handling Errors](https://pub.dev/packages/dio#handling-errors) documentation, it will return a DioError Object.

```dart
// DIO Example
Response response = await dio.get('https://google.com');
print(response.statusCode); // 500
print(response.data); // Contains a Dio Error object
```

The HTTP package works similarly.

```dart
var url = 'https://example.com/whatsit/create';
var response = await http.post(url, body: {'name': 'doodle', 'color': 'blue'});
print(response.statusCode); // 500
print(response.body); // Error message
```

This means in any case you are not receiving directly an error for Flutter, you have to handle the error yourself. For example, you could throw an error, if the status code is not 200.

```
if(response.statusCode == 200){
  // everything works as expected
} else {
  throw Error();
}
```

Comment: Normally I always do that, but now it always skip this line - **print(response.data)**.